# Z-Index Preventing Clicking on Navbar Link

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position, z-index

Can the z-index or positioning of an element prevent a user from clicking on a navbar link?

On my site http://www.tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/live-tour/live-tour.html, for some reason I am unable to click on any of the links in the navbar. Is this the cause of the z-index or positioning? How can I alleviate this problem and how can users in general avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not related to the z-index. Leave that alone. Your issue is misusing the `<header>` element. It is recommended you use one `<header>` in an HTML5 document although you can still do more than one. But in your case, you have your header styled and it is applying to both the nav and the intro.

Replace the intro in a div instead of a header like this:

```
<div class="intro">
    <div class="intro-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1 style="font-family: Montserrat,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;" class="brand-heading">Harriton TSA</h1>
                    <p class="intro-text" style="text-align:center;visibility:visible;">Take a virtual tour of our TSA Chapter and STEM program</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll" style="text-decoration:none;"><div id="scroll" style="font-size:22px;text-align:center;">Scroll</div><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And voila! You have your nav functionality back

Comment: Thank you for the effective fix!

Answer (score 0):

Z-index of the navigation bar should be of higher value than the rest of the page.